# dialout group missing

Tags: bash, users, group

I have debian8, (Jessie) and I am trying to add a user to the dialout group. 
Alas, that group doesn't exist. I would prefer not to add the user to the root or sudo group.

what should I do?

```
~$ groups
user1 user2 cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev lpadmin scanner bluetooth
```

How can I create the dialout group?

```
$sudo usermod -a -G dialout user1
```

executes without error, but I cannot see that I am a member of the dialout group, nor that any dialout group exists

Comment: I think the `groups` command will print only the groups you are a member of. Try `cut -d: -f1 /etc/group` to list all groups in the system and see if dialout group is present.

Comment: Check with `getent group  dialout`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Debian, the default groups are set up by `base-passwd`; the `dialout` group should always be present. If it isn't, you can use `update-passwd` to restore the expected configuration:

```
sudo update-passwd
```

(this will restore the system and user groups, but won't modify anything else).

You simply need to add your user to the group:

```
sudo adduser $(whoami) dialout
```

Comment: I logged out and logged back in, then it was evidently there.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can try the 'groupadd' command.

```
user@system:~$ groupadd
Usage: groupadd [options] GROUP

Options:
  -f, --force                  exit successfully if the group already exists,
                                and cancel -g if the GID is already used
  -g, --gid GID                 use GID for the new group
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -K, --key KEY=VALUE           override /etc/login.defs defaults
  -o, --non-unique              allow to create groups with duplicate
                                (non-unique) GID
  -p, --password PASSWORD       use this encrypted password for the new group
  -r, --system                  create a system account
```

Else, a lot of the time most Window Managers have a graphical user manager installed. For instance, under a Knoppix setup I have it under Menu -> Preferences -> Users and Groups